# DQN with action (obtained from some baseline algorithm) as part of input

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, reinforcement-learning

I have some base algorithm (that chooses an action and is static but based on rigorous statistical theory). This action is between 0 and 1 and continous,
$$ a_{baseline} \in (0,1) .$$ This means that the input vector X consists of $a_{baseline}$ and some additional inputs: $X_{i} = (a_{baseline}, x_{0,i}, x_{1,i},..)$

I want to improve said algorithm by using DQN and additional inputs (unused in the base estimator). I am using a simple Neural Net with 100 output nodes corresponding to a discretized version of the action space:
$$ a_{new} \in \{0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.99, 1.0\}.$$
**Note:** My data is special as it doens't fit into the usual RL realm: I only have one-step rewards. Hence in every state, I immediately have the rewards. Also the actions to not influence future states, as the states are just the data available at the current day in the timeseries. One could also think of it as a multi-armed bandit setting with full reward signal available in every state.

My network is as follows:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_actions, hidden_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_features, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, int(hidden_size/2))
        self.state_action_head = nn.Linear(int(hidden_size/2), num_actions)  # probabilistic mapping from states to actions
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.25)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        state_action_value = self.state_action_head(x)
        return state_action_value
```

I then trained the model by backpropagating the MSE loss between the estimated q_value and the actual q_value for all $a$ simultaneously:
$$loss = MSE(\hat{q}(s,a), q(s,a))$$

Do you think such an architecture makes sense?

I also tried trained tuning the model such that the new action $a_{new}$ should not be too far away from $a_{baseline}$. I did this by adding a MSE loss corresponding to the distance of $a_{baseline}$ and the corresponding $a_{new}$ (for all a simultaneously), i.e.:
$$loss = MSE(\hat{q}(s,a), q(s,a)) + MSE(a_{baseline}, a).$$

This didn't quite work out though and I don't know what I'm missing. I am also open to completely other architectures as I am just playing around a little.